# Packing the normal vector and tangent vector

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

In the deferred shading engine I'm working on, I currently store the normal vector in a buffer with the internal format `GL_RGBA16F`.
I was always aware that this could not be the best solution, but I had no time to deal with it.

Recently I read ["Survey of Efficient Representations for Independent Unit Vectors"](http://jcgt.org/published/0003/02/01/), which inspired me to use Octahedral Normal Vectors (ONV) and to change the buffer to `GL_RG16_SNORM`:

*Encode the normal vector (`vec3` to `vec2`)*:

```c
// Returns +/- 1
vec2 signNotZero( vec2 v )
{
    return vec2((v.x >= 0.0) ? +1.0 : -1.0, (v.y >= 0.0) ? +1.0 : -1.0);
}

// Assume normalized input. Output is on [-1, 1] for each component.
vec2 float32x3_to_oct( in vec3 v )
{
    // Project the sphere onto the octahedron, and then onto the xy plane
    vec2 p = v.xy * (1.0 / (abs(v.x) + abs(v.y) + abs(v.z)));
    // Reflect the folds of the lower hemisphere over the diagonals
    return (v.z <= 0.0) ? ((1.0 - abs(p.yx)) * signNotZero(p)) : p;
}
```

*Decode the normal vector (`vec2` to `vec3`)*:

```c
vec3 oct_to_float32x3( vec2 e )
{
    vec3 v = vec3(e.xy, 1.0 - abs(e.x) - abs(e.y));
    if (v.z < 0) v.xy = (1.0 - abs(v.yx)) * signNotZero(v.xy);
    return normalize(v);
}
```

Since I have implemented an anisotropic light model right now, it is necessary to store the tangent vector as well as the normal vector. I want to store both vectors in one and the same color attachment of the frame buffer. That brings me to my question. What is a efficient compromise to pack a unit normal vector and tangent vector in a buffer?
Of course it would be easy with the algorithms from the paper to store the normal vector in the `RG` channels and the tangent vector in the `BA` channels of a `GL_RGBA16_SNORM` buffer, and this is my current implementation too.
But since the normal vector an the tangent vector are always **orthogonal**, there must be more elegant way, which either increases accuracy or saves memory.

So the real question is: How can I take advantage of the fact that I know that 2 vectors are orthogonal? Can I store both vectors in an `GL_RGB16_SNORM` buffer and if not can I improve the accuracy when I pack them to a `GL_RGBA16_SNORM` buffer.

Comment: This idea might work: store the normal in spherical polar format (2 floats), and an additional float value to specify the azimuthal angle of the tangent. Since the tangent is constrained to a plane, just one value would be enough to specify it, *except* in the case where the normal is in the X-Y plane. In this case we must change the meaning of the additional angle (e.g. angle from the Z-axis. This will need to be considered during pre-processing)

Answer (score 1):

The following considerations are purely mathematical and I have no experience with their practicality. However, I think that especially Option 2 might be a viable candidate.

Both of the following options have in common how they state the problem: Given a normal (that you can reconstruct using ONV), how can one encode the tangent with a single number.

### Option 1

The first option is very close to what meowgoesthedog suggested. Define an arbitrary reference vector (e.g. `(0, 0, 1)`). Then encode the tangent as the angle (normalized to the `[-1, 1]` range) that you need to rotate this vector about the normal to match the tangent direction (after projecting on the tangent plane, of course). You will need two different reference vectors (or even three) and choose the correct one depending on the normal. You don't want the reference vector to be parallel to the normal. I assume that this is computationally more expensive than the second option but that would need measuring. But you would get a uniform error distribution in return.

### Option 2

Let's consider the plane orthogonal to the tangent. This plane can be defined either by the tangent or by two vectors that lie in the plane. We know one vector: the surface normal. If we know a second vector `v`, we can calculate the tangent as `t = normalize(cross(normal, v))`. To encode this vector, we can prescribe two components and solve for the remaining one. E.g. let our vector be `(1, 1, x)`. Then, to encode the vector, we need to find `x`, such that `cross((1, 1, x), normal)` is parallel to the tangent. This can be done with some simple arithmetic. Again, you would need a few different vector templates to account for all scenarios. In the end, you have a scheme whose encoder is more complex but whose decoder couldn't be simpler. The error distribution will not be as uniform as in Option 1, but should be ok for a reasonable choice of vector templates.